# Php/Ajax/jQuery/Javascript program works on one host and not the other. THE IMPOSSIBLE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I do not have any particular code to post as I don't even think its a code issue. There are no errors reporting to give me any direction to follow.

The problem:
I have social-media-Facebook-like wall script installed on multiple hosts. So lets label them HA1 and HB2 and HB3.

The php/ajax/jquery mechanism that creates a wall post works on the HB2 site. Its flawless. You type your post, it appears on the wall with no refresh -amazing. All the other MySQL backed aspects of the scripts work fine too.

Now, sites HA1 and HB3, I dropped the SAME files into. Same php.ini, .htaccess files, and locations. I even setup the database, the user, and then attached the two in the same order. Now I go to the script, I do the same function, try to post on the wall and tt does two things, one it acts like it worked but shows no post, or it gets hung up thinking and not completing the action. Either way, no post. All the other functions backed by the database, that don't require ajax/jQuery to create that refresh-less get/post action, work just fine.

I have cleared the cache on my browser, uploaded , an uploaded again. I even called the host to have them compare the two accounts they host to tell me if anything is different between them. She said the only difference is that one has perl modules and the other doesn't. Irrelevant. I have tried so many different troubleshooting methods I can't list them all.

I went through both cPanels and this is the only error I could locate on both of them that referenced the same file.

```
[Fri Nov 04 19:17:29.353142 2016] [rewrite:warn] [pid 963334:tid     140070732338944] AH00665: RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored. (/home/newsamson/public_html/test/.htaccess:4)
[Fri Nov 04 19:17:27.568743 2016] [rewrite:warn] [pid 963334:tid 140070732338944] AH00665: RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-d' is not supported and will be ignored. (/home/newsamson/public_html/test/.htaccess:5)
```

I don't know enough about this error to know if this is apart of the problem. Not to mention, even though the errors are on both accounts, one of the accounts it appears on... is the working account for this same script.

Any help would be absolutely appreciated thank you.

EDIT: Suggestions thus far - 1. could be different Apache-mod_rewrite versions, don't clone php.ini files to different host accounts.

Edit: Need more help!!

Comment: You are probably using different versions of apache/mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thank you @Dekel I will check into that.

Comment: you should not arbitrarily copy `php.ini` files between systems. that is surely the problem. you could have php modules on one php.ini that aren't even installed in another server. hopefully you made a backup of the originals before copying.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Iwrestledabearonce. However, I have troubleshooted it by tailoring the php.ini files to their respective hosting account. Still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

It was a caching issue. The script was robust and to heavy on the cache. The solution was essentially making the script run better so it would constantly update data fresh script wide, instead of letting it all grow heavily in the cache.